# Dynamically Creating Variables and DataFrames from A List

Tags: python, pandas, dynamic-programming

I am trying to create summaries of unique buyers for each of the different products in my Sales table. My target outcome is as follows:

|  | CustSeg | UNIQUE_PROD1_CUST |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | High | 7 |
| 1 | Low | 8 |
| 2 | Mid | 4 |

This summary is created and assigned to variable as below:

```
# Count of DISTINCT PROD1 CUSTOMERS

PROD1_CUST = (
    Sales_Df.loc[(Sales_Df.Prod1_Qty > 0)]
    .groupby("CustSeg")["CustID"]
    .count()
    .reset_index(name="UNIQUE_PROD1_CUST")
)

PROD1_CUST
```

The **Sales_Df** dataframe can be replicated thus:

```
Sales_Qty = {
    "CustID": ['C01',   'C02',  'C03',  'C04',  'C05',  'C06',  'C07',  'C08',  'C09',  'C10',  'C11',  'C12',  'C13',  'C14',  'C15',  'C16',  'C17',  'C18',  'C19',  'C20', ],
    "CustSeg": ['High',     'High',     'Mid',  'High',     'Low',  'Low',  'Low',  'Low',  'Low',  'Mid',  'Low',  'Low',  'Mid',  'Low',  'High',     'High',     'High',     'High',     'Mid',  'Low',  ],
    "Prod1_Qty": [8,    7,  12,     15,     7,  15,     7,  8,  3,  15,     0,  3,  4,  4,  7,  11,     12,     12,     6,  1, ],
    "Prod2_Qty": [2,    5,  0,  1,  14,     15,     3,  1,  11,     0,  5,  11,     12,     8,  6,  15,     7,  4,  3,  10, ],
    "Prod3_Qty": [13,   4,  0,  11,     3,  5,  11,     11,     10,     14,     2,  4,  3,  14,     14,     10,     5,  0,  0,  9,  ],
    "Prod4_Qty": [11,   15,     2,  0,  6,  2,  12,     14,     11,     15,     5,  14,     13,     0,  10,     2,  13,     11,     12,     15, ],
    "Prod5_Qty": [9,    15,     5,  4,  9,  0,  13,     9,  8,  11,     10,     12,     8,  3,  14,     11,     9,  15,     8,  14, ]
}
Sales_Df = pd.DataFrame(Sales_Qty)
Sales_Df
```

Now, in real life, the dataframe's shape is larger by far (at least (5000000, 130)), which makes manual repeat of the summary for each of the products tenuous so I am trying to automate the creation of the variables and the summary. I am approaching the task with the following steps.

```
# Extract the proposed variable names from the dataframe column names.
all_cols = Sales_Df.columns.values.tolist()

# Remove non-product quantity columns from the list
not_prod_cols = ["CustSeg", "CustID"]
prod_cols = [x for x in all_cols if x not in not_prod_cols]
```

I know the next things should be:

1. creating the variable names from the list **prod_cols** and storing
   those variables in a list - let's name the list **prod_dfs**

   ```
   prod_dfs = []
   ```
2. Creating the dynamic formula that creates the dataframes and append
   their variable names to **prod_dfs** using the "logic" below.

   ```
   for x in prod_cols:
        x[:-4] + "_CUST" = (
           Sales_Df.loc[(Sales_Df.x > 0)]
           .groupby("CustSeg")["CustID"]
           .count()
           .reset_index(name="UNIQUE" + x[:-4] + "_CUST")
       )
   ```

```
prod_dfs.append(x)
```

This is where I am stuck. Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for sharing a reproducible example, and seems like you have made good progress. If I understand correctly, you want to be able to compute the number of unique customers per segment who have purchased a given item.

To follow your approach, you could iterate through the product columns, compute the counts, and assign this to a results dataframe:

```py
prod_cols = [col for col in Sales_Df.columns if col.startswith('Prod')]
result = None
for prod in prod_cols:
    counts = (
        Sales_Df
        .loc[Sales_Df[prod] > 0]
        .groupby('CustSeg')
        [prod]
        .count()
    )
    if result is None:
        result = counts.to_frame()
    else:
        result[prod] = counts
```

| CustSeg | Prod1_Qty | Prod2_Qty | Prod3_Qty | Prod4_Qty | Prod5_Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| High | 7 | 7 | 6 | 6 | 7 |
| Low | 8 | 9 | 9 | 8 | 8 |
| Mid | 4 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 4 |

This would help you in the second dimension, in the sense that you do not have to write this aggregation code for all your columns.

However, the resulting code is not very efficient because it does O(m) groupby operations, where m is the number of columns.

You can get your desired result with slightly different logic.

1. Form groups of each customer segment.
2. For each product, count the number of purchasers
3. Combine the results

This one liner implements this logic.

```py
Sales_Df.drop('CustID', axis=1).groupby('CustSeg').apply(lambda group: (group>0).sum(axis=0))
```

Note that we first drop `CustID` because in your example, after grouping by `CustSeg`, it is the only column that is not a product quantity.

As an aside: consider reviewing the [pandas indexing basics](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#basics). You may find it easier to use the syntax of `df['A']` rather than `df.A` because it allows you to use other programming constructs more effectively.

Comment: Thank you for providing the solution using the logic I proposed and for providing a better approach. I am very grateful. The advice on pandas indexing basics is also much appreciated - I will take that to heart. Have a great day.